# Parsing a BigRational efficiently

Tags: c#, performance, parsing, rational-numbers

I'm using the `BigRational` beta off the BCL CodePlex ([bcl.codeplex.com](http://bcl.codeplex.com)), and I realized it had no parsing method, so I tried to write one. However, it's quite inefficient (5.5ms for a 254 character number). That's over 45x slower than the BigInteger implementation. I'd like to lower it to .5ms if that's even possible.

```
private static Regex DigitDotDigit = new Regex(@"^(\-|\+)?(\d+\.\d+)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static Regex PlainDigit = new Regex(@"^(\-|\+)?\d+$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static Regex DigitSlashDigit = new Regex(@"^(\-|\+)?\d+/\d+$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static Regex DotDigit = new Regex(@"^(\-|\+)?(\.\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static bool RegexInitiated = false;
public static bool TryParse(string parse, out BigRational result)
{
    if (DigitDotDigit.IsMatch(parse))
    {
        int zeros;
        bool isNegative = false;
        string[] parts = parse.TrimStart('+').Split('.');
        parts[1] = parts[1].TrimEnd('0');
        if (parts[0].StartsWith("-"))
        {
            isNegative = true;
            parts[0] = parts[0].Substring(1);
        }
        BigRational whole = new BigRational(BigInteger.Parse(parts[0]), BigInteger.Zero, BigInteger.One);
        BigRational decimalPart = new BigRational(BigInteger.Parse(parts[1]), BigInteger.Zero, BigInteger.One);
        zeros = parts[1].Length - parts[1].TrimStart('0').Length;
        toSubtract = toSubtract + zeros;
        if (zeros > 0)
        {
            toSubtract = toSubtract - 1;
        }
        while (toSubtract != 0)
        {
            decimalPart /= 10;
            toSubtract = toSubtract - 1;
        }
        result = whole + decimalPart;
        if (isNegative)
        {
            result = -result;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else if (DotDigit.IsMatch(parse))
    {
        return TryParse("0" + parse, out result);
    }
    else if (PlainDigit.IsMatch(parse))
    {
        parse = parse.TrimStart('+');
        if (parse.StartsWith("-"))
        {
            result = new BigRational(-BigInteger.Parse(parse), BigInteger.Zero, BigInteger.One);
            return true;
        }
        result = new BigRational(BigInteger.Parse(parse), BigInteger.Zero, BigInteger.One);
        return true;
    }
    else if (DigitSlashDigit.IsMatch(parse))
    {
        string[] parts = parse.TrimStart('+').Split('/');
        if (parts[0].StartsWith("-"))
        {
            parts[0] = parts[0].Substring(1);
            result = -(new BigRational(BigInteger.Parse(parts[0]), BigInteger.Parse(parts[1])));
            return true;
        }
        result = new BigRational(BigInteger.Parse(parts[0]), BigInteger.Parse(parts[1]));
        return true;
    }
    result = BigInteger.Zero;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think that before worrying about performance, you should make sure that your code actually works correctly (hint: try parsing numbers like `0.1`, or even just `1`). And you should also include the whole method, so that we don't have to guess what the rest of it contains (even if it's quite obvious).

Comment: Whoops, missed the copy and paste. Wait one second. And it worked fine in ~25 tests that I did...

Comment: @svick Fixed that behaviour. Should've remembered to use >=.

Comment: It's still not completely fixed. Try `0.1001`.

Comment: Setting a value in the middle of an expression is confusing, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: More efficient. It's the key here.

Comment: It really wouldn't be more efficient than setting `zeros` first and then using that value.

Comment: @svick Edited it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, I found out now, was that if I moved the `Regex`es to private fields, and then used those, after the first use it will radically drop down to .4ms, and that's including a `WriteLine` call. So the real hotspot in this method was the `Regex`. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You might also want to look into compiling your [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045.aspx).  Look for the section "Interpreted vs Compiled Regular Expressions".  Compiling them is a huge speed improvement.

Comment: Thought it did that by default, thanks for warning me :)